# Bootstrap search button is not in line with input field

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

ı am trying to make a change search section on ready template of [ansonika](http://www.ansonika.com/citytours/index_7.html)

As a result I am getting this image that you can see searchnow is not in the same line.
[image]

Here you can see the code I have that for that section.

```
<section id="search_container">
<div id="search">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#tours" data-toggle="tab">Tours</a></li>

                </ul>

                <div class="tab-content">
                    <div class="tab-pane active" id="tours">
                    <h3>Search Tours in Paris</h3>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Destination</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstname_booking" name="firstname_booking" placeholder="Type your search terms">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                     <label><i class="icon-calendar-7"></i> Date</label>
                                    <input class="date-pick form-control" data-date-format="M d, D" type="text">

                                </div>

                            </div>

                            <button class="btn_1 green" type="submit"><i class="icon-search"></i>Search now</button>


                        </div><!-- End row -->



                    </div><!-- End rab -->


                </div>
</div>
```

How can I put this search box in the same row.

Thanks.

Comment: Try this, is this what you mean? let me know if it helps. https://jsfiddle.net/54rLbrsc/

Comment: I have tried by creating anotehr column but result was same

Comment: have you tried the fiddle?

Comment: http://www.a2b4.net/acity/index_7.html you can see here

Comment: You can actually build another row, but how you want it when on mobile? if you turn off the responsive and only use dekstop then use different row.

Comment: putting in another row is easy. What i want is in line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[update]

[image]

In your label css, i saw that it add another 5 px of bottom margin to the `<label>` so for **hack** solution, i add an br with another 5 px bottom margin to get the result.

```
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <div style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
            <br>
        </div>
        <button class="btn_1 green" type="submit"><i class="icon-search"></i>Search now</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: i think your css already been edited too much, can you use the bootsrap manually like in my update.

Comment: i gave many tries. Thanks for your help. will find a solution.

Comment: Here, i use hack solution that may be can help you. The custom css adding some 5  px to the label. so it looks like that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is simple:
You have provided labels and inputs in the rest and only a input in this one, so the input occupies the label's place.
There is no neat solution other than to widen the entire div and have the entire row inline.
The alternative is to create a label or a cssed empty div that pushes the button down.
Or you could add inline styling for the button using the 'top' and 'position' properties.
I also recommend using a column for this.It is lot cleaner that way.

Comment: i have added ' <div class="col-md-4">
                                 <div class="form-group">
                                      <label></label>
                             <button class="btn_1 green" type="submit"><i class="icon-search"></i>Search now</button>
                                    </div>
        </div>' but no way it is same

Comment: I did mention about the top and position properties too...I checked ...set position:relative and top:27px...